# How to encode time information in LSTM prediction problem

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build a model based on a recent google paper called "Scalable and Accurate Deep Learning for Electronic Health Records". The paper describes how to embed medical data for downstream prediction tasks.

In the supplementary material, they have a section describing how to embed medical data by doing the following (pic attached below too):

1) Take the raw medical data per patient per time step and embed them (like how its done in word embeddings)

2) Concatenate all history of that patient for that timestep together into a long vector

2a) For multiple information of the same type, average embeddings using a learned weighting

3) Create another vector that contains time information (seconds)

[image]

I am rather new with LSTMs, but I found some code that I wanted to modify in order to take in the embeddings and time information:

```
class LSTMClassifier(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, vocab_size, label_size):
    super(LSTMClassifier, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim)
    self.hidden2label = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, label_size)
    self.hidden = self.init_hidden()

def init_hidden(self):
    # the first is the hidden h
    # the second is the cell  c
    return (autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, 1, self.hidden_dim)),
            autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, 1, self.hidden_dim)))

def forward(self, sentence):
    embeds = self.embeddings(sentence)
    x = embeds.view(len(sentence), 1, -1)
    lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(x, self.hidden)
    y = self.hidden2label(lstm_out[-1])
    log_probs = F.log_softmax(y)
    return log_probs
```

Finally, in the supplementary material, it states that:

> The sequence of embeddings were further reduced down to a shorter
>   sequence. Typically, the shorter sequences were split into time-steps
>   of 12 hours where the embeddings for all features within a category in
>   the same day were combined using weighted averaging. The weighted
>   averaging is done by associating each feature with a non-negative
>   weight that is trained jointly with the model. These weights are also
>   used for prediction attribution. The log of the average time-delta
>   divided by a factor (controlled by a hyperparameter) at each time-step
>   is also embedded into a small floating-point vector (which is also
>   randomly initialized) and concatenated to the input embedding at each
>   time-step.

My general question is: How do I actually go about inserting this time vector?

I am confused because it states that the sequences were split into 12-hour time steps. If that's the case, why the need for a time vector? It then later states that you can just simply concatenate the time vector to the input embedding. Why would a simple concatenation like that work and how would the model know to associate that time information with the appropriate part of the input? The actual implement is kind of lost on me so any guidance would be very much appreciated!